# The purpose of GC.Collect()

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, operating-system

I'm new to .NET and CLR, just a question on CLR garbage collection.

My textbook describes one of purposes to use GC.Collect() is

**Your application has just finished allocating an extremely large number of objects
and you want to remove as much of the acquired memory as soon as possible.**

Below is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Estimated bytes on heap: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
Car refToMyCar = new Car();
Console.WriteLine("\nGeneration of refToMyCar is: {0}", GC.GetGeneration(refToMyCar));
GC.Collect(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
Console.WriteLine("\nGeneration of refToMyCar is: {0}", GC.GetGeneration(refToMyCar));
Console.WriteLine("Estimated bytes on heap: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
```

and the outout is:

```
Estimated bytes on heap: 29900

Generation of refToMyCar is: 0

Generation of refToMyCar is: 1

Estimated bytes on heap: 39648
```

so here is my question:

1- GC.Collect() seems to only mark the item pointed by refToMyCar from Generation 0 to Generation 1, nothing has been "free", since Generation 1 means an object that has survived a garbage collection. Let's say before GC.Collect() there is 10mb of available size left on heap(a total of 100mb for example), and after GC.Collect() , there is still only 10mb left on heap, so what's the point to call GC.Collect()? isn't we want available size to be 100mb 100% available?

EDIT:
Discard my previous question

if I change it to an object array, it is even stranger:

```
Console.WriteLine("Estimated bytes on heap: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
object[] refToMyCar = new object[50000];
for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
   refToMyCar[i] = new object();
Console.WriteLine("\nGeneration of refToMyCar is: {0}", GC.GetGeneration(refToMyCar));       
Console.WriteLine("Estimated bytes on heap: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
```

the output is:

```
Estimated bytes on heap: 29900

Generation of refToMyCar is: 2
Estimated bytes on heap: 836140
Press any key to continue . . .
```

how come refToMyCar is Generation 2 which is s an object that has survived more than one sweep of the garbage collector? we haven't called any implicit or explicit GC.Collect() yet?

Comment: **No Disrespect** but you are asking these question many times a day, all these questions can be researched (which it seems you a capable of) instead of asking here, most of these questions have been asked many times before, and there are usually blogs and other offsite resources that will give you more in-depth knowledge and a better understanding than this question and answer format

Comment: Also you have actually asked 3 questions in one, which is frowned upon

Comment: `I'm new to .NET and CLR` At the risk of sounding rude, wait a year before investigating playing with `GC.Collect()`. It is incredibly rare that you need to call it manually - and very unlikely you'll run into one of those scenarios in the kind of development you are doing. For now, your mental model should be 'let the GC do its thing - I'll leave it alone'. We could give you detailed answers for each of your questions - but honestly it will go over your head _right now_. The finer details of GC took years to settle in to my brain.

Comment: Everything you need to know is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals

Comment: @mjwills  I have one year of C# development experience, I said I'm new because I'm not senior. OK, I just want to know why refToMyCar is generation 2, shouldn't it be generation 0? could you have a look at my edited post. Thx

Comment: `I have one year of C# development experience` 1 month or 1 year - it makes no difference. Wait another year or two. ;) `OK, I just want to know why refToMyCar is generation 2, shouldn't it be generation 0?` Where does it promise it will be Generation 0? Also, read up on the **Large Object Heap**. Again, I strongly suggest putting this aside for a year or two and coming back to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The garbage collector is not allowed to collect objects that are still referenced. Since you're keeping a reference to `refToMyCar` to get its generation later, it cannot be collected. If you want to observe the object being reclaimed, you can use `WeakReference` instead. Also, you need to run without the debugger - to help with debugging, the debugger makes it so that all references survive until they get out of scope (i.e. the block/method body ends).

In your second case, you're allocating a large object. .NET will place those on a special heap, the large object heap. Those objects have special rules - they're always considered generation two, and they cannot be moved (unless you explicitly ask the GC to do that). You need to pay special attention to large objects.

Of course, both of these behaviours are described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals).

The basic rule dealing with `GC.Collect` is pretty simple - don't use it. There's very few cases where there's any benefit to doing so, and most of the time, you're just wasting CPU, memory and making objects survive *longer* than they otherwise would.

Answer (score 0):

After yours `GC.Collect()` you have usage of the variable you're trying to collect:

```
Console.WriteLine("Estimated bytes on heap: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
Car refToMyCar = new Car();
Console.WriteLine("\nGeneration of refToMyCar is: {0}", GC.GetGeneration(refToMyCar));
GC.Collect(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced);

// after removing reference to the variable it's been collected and will not survive to generation 1
// Console.WriteLine("\nGeneration of refToMyCar is: {0}", GC.GetGeneration(refToMyCar));
Console.WriteLine("Estimated bytes on heap: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
```

That happens because of how memory management perform and if somewhere in your code you're referencing variable - it will survive and its generation might be updated. That's why you should be careful about closures and tree structures.

### Output:

```
Estimated bytes on heap: 29988

Generation of refToMyCar is: 0
Estimated bytes on heap: 29448
```

---

Also regarding your other questions - I believe you can't free up 100% of heap memory just because you have to store the program itself somewhere, static class memory allocation - GC is a good example of it.